# Force extension become inactive

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

With manifest v3 the service workers become inactive after few seconds, but they stay active for a long time if devtools is opened (way beyond 5 minutes).

I need to test how my extension handles its active/inactive cycles. How can I force it to become inactive while devtools is opened?

*(can't use devtools persistent logs for action popup, because it's being cleared each time)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open any visible page of your extension like the popup or the options
2. Open devtools for that page (right-click the page, then choose "inspect")
3. Go to `Application` tab, then `Service Worker` on the left.
4. Now you can click `Stop` and `Start` to control the background script. You can also debug it and set breakpoints in this devtools.
   [image]

If your extension doesn't have any page, open any file in a tab e.g. `chrome-extension://ID/manifest.json` where ID is the id of your extension. A quick method of doing it is to right-click any file of your extension in devtools Sources panel, then choose "Open in new tab".

Comment: How can we restart the extension service worker from inside the extension code itself? Use case: I would like to test how well my service worker performs in the real world in the worst case, outside of just manual testing. By having the service worker terminate itself on its own every few seconds, I can get much better robustness testing of the worker.

Answer (score 2):

You can also stop/start/unregister/inspect service-worker in this url `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`